# Message passing model in clojure for concurrency

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure, programming-languages

I am inquiring to know whether or not one can use the programming language Clojure for a message passing concurrency model i.e. no shared memory region between two processes/threads.

I wish to use Clojure for a few reasons, namely, I know and like Common Lisp and I would like to a functional programming language. I don't know too much about either Clojure or Concurrency however from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure#Language_features) Clojure implements concurrency through software-transactional-memory,an agent system and a dynamic var system.

1. Can Clojure implement a message passing concurrency model?
2. If not, what other languages

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can Clojure implement a message passing concurrency model?

Yes sure. It is already implemented for Clojure. Check [Pulsar](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/pulsar/) project. It looks really promising and ready for the prime time.

Of course, nothing stops you from using [Akka.io](http://akka.io/) since it is a JVM project (by using Clojure's built-in Java interop). But Pulsar is created with Clojure in mind.

> what other languages?

Erlang is the undisputed champion when it comes to Actors model.

Comment: Is there any advantage for a language to have this model as a language feature?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus What do you mean? You mean if actors model is implemented as part of the language and not as a library?

Comment: Yes, is there any benefit of having this specific concurrency model built into the language?

Comment: I don't think there is really much of a difference between having this model built into the language vs. available using a library, at least not in a language like Clojure. Take a look at [Pulsar's user manual](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/pulsar/#user-manual). Setup (as with all/most Clojure libraries) is relatively simple, then the functions you need are readily available in the library.

Comment: I would think the speed would have to do more with how the functions are implemented than whether they are in clojure.core or somewhere else. I could be wrong, though.